# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Will not connect to wired internet after update

Tags: updates, internet, wired

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
I can connect to my router, but internet does not work after the last update.

`Ping 8.8.8.8` gives me `(8.8.8.8) 56(84 bytes of data`.

I try `inconfig` but says I do not have `net-tools` installed. I can not download anything as I do not have internet.

I have also rebooted several times. tried unplugging ethernet, plugging back in (obviously works though as it connects to my router via ethernet and my other computer is connect via the same line in from a split box)

I newer to Ubuntu so I will try to answer your questions as best as possible and edit this question with updated info as I learn.

If someone has suggestions for paid support I am happy with that too.

Thank you!

APRIL 6 '23 - RESOLVED

Here are some results from what I have tried already with no results.

[Can't use Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Lenovo ThinkPad T460 after installing and uninstalling Proton VPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428012/cant-use-firefox-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t460-after-installing/1428445#1428445)

```
`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNbvi.jpg


kdl2020@Linux-Desktop:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 30  2022 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf



 `ip a`    https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktfHK.jpg

kdl2020@Linux-Desktop:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:80:fd:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.75/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 67643sec preferred_lft 67643sec
    inet6 2001:56a:7cb1:6800:7720:666d:cefe:e505/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3892sec preferred_lft 3592sec
    inet6 2001:56a:7cb1:6800:90b4:5f0a:5888:5eda/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3892sec preferred_lft 3592sec
    inet6 fe80::6322:c850:6c62:64e5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:9c:d1:53:13:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ipv6leakintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:b4:32:1a:17:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6a9f:5650:3bf9:b592/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: pvpnksintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:e6:a3:32:21:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.85.0.1/24 brd 100.85.0.255 scope global noprefixroute pvpnksintrf0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b6c4:b65:9e35:a8c9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ip a` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How can I do that with no internet connection?

Comment: Are you using stubby for encrypted DNS (assuming not)? You need to comment out (#) within the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, #DNSStubListener=yes #DNSStubListenerExtra=

Comment: Got it, great idea, thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming not as I haven't heard of stubby before

Comment: Are you using a VPN? Did you correctly set DNS nameservers in the VPN configuration?

Comment: @chili555 I have a VPN, however, it is quit and not running. I also do not have the kill switch on. Internet always has worked when I keep it off or turn it on. I have also tried turning the VPN on and it can't find any internet to connect to.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428012/cant-use-firefox-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t460-after-installing/1428445#1428445

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, I just tried that. Other than the fact I use wired internet, I followed the same steps. No good results.

Comment: I am quite confident that this is due to the VPN settings. I know little to nothing about VPN and so I have no other useful suggestions.

Comment: @chili555 Would there be anything else to check with a VPN though? The app is quit as well. When I opened it, it wouldn't even connect to internet either.

Comment: As I said, I know nothing at all about VPN configuration. I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNS not resolved on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426658/dns-not-resolved-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS problem. And since you mentioned using a VPN, it could possibly be related to that.

Does this help?

[DNS not resolved on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426658/dns-not-resolved-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

When you were configuring Ubuntu did you input the network settings manually or automatically? Possibly try a reinstall and do automatic network. I was having a similar problem and was able to use automatic to install network manager and havent been having any problems from there with network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for coming in to help! You may want to add this as a comment instead of an answer. 
I didn't need to ever set it up since I have wired internet, it just automatically is connected. I have removed the profile. Rebooted, and when I open up settings it is automatically there again since the ethernet cable is connected.